# Stacks python3 abstract data types

Tags: list, iterator, python-3.2

Ok so I am trying to input "Hello World!" and I want the output to be "dlroW olleH"
My code prints the opposite one by one.
How do I fix this?

```
class Stack:

    def __init__(self):
        self.__items = []

    def push(self, item):
        self.__items.append(item)

    def pop(self):
        return self.__items.pop()

    def peek(self):
        return self.__items[len(self.__items)-1]

    def is_empty(self):
        return len(self.__items) == 0

    def size(self):
        return len(self.__items)
    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.__items)


x = Stack()

userinput = input("enter ")
for letter in userinput:
    x.push(letter)


while x:
    print(x.pop())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, every call to `print()` writes to a new line on the screen.

You can change this with the [`end` argument to `print()`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print), like so:

```
print(x.pop(), end='')
```

Then, all of the characters in the string will be printed all on the same line.

You can also add a plain call to `print()` at the end to add a final end-of-line.

Comment: Would you recommend a place where you can learn all about abstract data types. It seems that there isnt a good place on the internet.

Comment: I’d recommend the book *Object-Oriented Software Construction* by Bertrand Meyer. Hopefully you have access to a library that has it. An older edition would be fine too.

Comment: I took a quick look at the newer edition, and unfortunately it seemed very overcomplicated. I read the 1988 edition a long time ago, and remember it fondly, but don’t have a copy nearby to check if it’s as good as I remember it. [You can use worldcat.org](http://www.worldcat.org/title/object-oriented-software-construction/oclc/17675237) to find it in a library.